# C# callback function in third party dll correctly implemented?

Tags: c#, dll, callback

Currently I'm using a third party DLL for a printer. It's a C# wrapper for a C++ DLL, so it can be used in a C# application. The method for printing contains a callback function that should be called when printing is done. However, I can't get it to work, so I'm wondering if I'm implementing it correctly.

The (shortened) method of this print and callback function is:

```cs
public class PrinterWrapper 
{
    public uint Print(CallbackFunction callbackFunction);

    public delegate void CallbackFunction();
}
```

In another class I'm using the print function and try to test the callback this way:

```cs
class Foo {
    private void callback() {
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test");
    }

    public void Print() {
    {
        PrinterWrapper wrapper = new PrinterWrapper();
        wrapper.Print(this.callback);
        wrapper.Print(new PrinterWrapper.CallbackFunction(this.callback));
    }
}
```

I've tried both version of calling the Print method (both should be the same), but I'm not getting a callback. Instead, I get an APPCRASH just when the print is ready. Did some searching, found out I could catch the exception with the setting

```xml
<runtime>
    <legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy enabled="true" />
</runtime>
```

It tells me it's a read/write memory protection exception. The event log also shows an error, right before my application crashes:

```
Application: Application.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
```

So it looks like the third party DLL is trying to access memory it doesn't have access to. The documentation says that the callback argument is a pointer (that's for the original C++ DLL). There is no documentation for the C# wrapper DLL.

With this info, did I correctly make use of the callback function or do I have to change something to get it working?

Comment: This `new PrinterWrapper.CallbackFunction(this.callback)` is not valid C# declaration

Comment: If `PrinterWrapper` works through p/invoke, you should decorate a callback using `[UnmanagedFunctionPointer]` attribute

Comment: Thanks to your comment I found the solution. The implementation of the callback method was incorrect. Thanks to your remark and some searching I corrected my implementation and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

Had a wrong implementation of the callback delegate. Fixed it and it now works.